Plymouth remove error after upgrading to 24.04 LTS
I have tried upgrading my Raspberry Pi 5, 8GB to Ubuntu 24.04 LTS, but it failed while removing Plymouth (postinst script). I have looked into it and apparently update-initramfs -u -k all is failing because of no permission. I executed it with sudo then.
This gave me this error:
ouldn't find DTB bcm2712-rpi-5-b.dtb on the following paths: /etc/flash-kernel/dtbs /usr/lib/linux-image-5.13.0-1028-raspi /lib/firmware/5.13.0-1028-raspi/device-tree/
Installing  into /boot/dtbs/5.13.0-1028-raspi/./bcm2712-rpi-5-b.dtb
cp: cannot stat '': No such file or directory
run-parts: /etc/initramfs/post-update.d//flash-kernel exited with return code 1

I have tried:
sudo apt-get autoclean
sudo apt reinstall plymouth
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt-get install --reinstall dpkg
sudo apt --fix-broken install

I don't know what to do now.
uname -a: Linux ubuntu 6.8.0-1007-raspi #7-Ubuntu
sudo apt --fix-broken install and other commands gave me:
sudo apt --fix-broken install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  plymouth
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 1262 kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 210831 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing plymouth (24.004.60-1ubuntu7) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-6.8.0-1007-raspi
^HUsing DTB: bcm2712-rpi-5-b.dtb
Installing /lib/firmware/6.8.0-1007-raspi/device-tree/broadcom/bcm2712-rpi-5-b.dtb into /boot/dtbs/6.8.0-1007-raspi/./bcm2712-rpi-5-b.dtb
Taking backup of bcm2712-rpi-5-b.dtb.
Installing new bcm2712-rpi-5-b.dtb.
flash-kernel: deferring update (trigger activated)
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-6.5.0-1020-raspi
Using DTB: bcm2712-rpi-5-b.dtb
Installing /lib/firmware/6.5.0-1020-raspi/device-tree/broadcom/bcm2712-rpi-5-b.dtb into /boot/dtbs/6.5.0-1020-raspi/./bcm2712-rpi-5-b.dtb
Taking backup of bcm2712-rpi-5-b.dtb.
Installing new bcm2712-rpi-5-b.dtb.
flash-kernel: deferring update (trigger activated)
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-6.5.0-1017-raspi
Using DTB: bcm2712-rpi-5-b.dtb
Installing /lib/firmware/6.5.0-1017-raspi/device-tree/broadcom/bcm2712-rpi-5-b.dtb into /boot/dtbs/6.5.0-1017-raspi/./bcm2712-rpi-5-b.dtb
Taking backup of bcm2712-rpi-5-b.dtb.
Installing new bcm2712-rpi-5-b.dtb.
flash-kernel: deferring update (trigger activated)
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.13.0-1028-raspi
Using DTB: bcm2712-rpi-5-b.dtb
Couldn't find DTB bcm2712-rpi-5-b.dtb on the following paths: /etc/flash-kernel/dtbs /usr/lib/linux-image-5.13.0-1028-raspi /lib/firmware/5.13.0-1028-raspi/device-tree/
Installing  into /boot/dtbs/5.13.0-1028-raspi/./bcm2712-rpi-5-b.dtb
cp: cannot stat '': No such file or directory
run-parts: /etc/initramfs/post-update.d//flash-kernel exited with return code 1
dpkg: error processing package plymouth (--remove):
 installed plymouth package post-removal script subprocess returned error exit status 1
dpkg: too many errors, stopping
Errors were encountered while processing:
 plymouth
Processing was halted because there were too many errors.
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

